# Get list of data from a column from a database, depending on the data in another column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

**Desc:** In the controller I download the overtime list from database (SQL Server / Entity Framework) and sum it up to one variable (it works now).

**Problem:** I need to select data from the database (list) from the "Minus" column, but only where option "2" is selected from the "dropdown" column.

And subtract the sum of downloaded data from my current total sum.

**Controller:**

```
var userName = "MIPA";
var numberYear = 2020;
var numberMonth = 6;

// downloading the overtime list from each previous month from the database
var overtimeListVariable = _ecpContext.Card
                                      .Where(x => x.Login == userName && 
                                                  x.Year == numberYear && 
                                                  x.Month < numberMonth)
                                      .Select(b => string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.overtimeList) ? TimeSpan.Zero : TimeSpan.Parse(b.overtimeList))
                                      .ToList();

// Calculate sum
var sumOvertimeListVariable = overtimeListVariable.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (t1, t2) => t1 + t2);
```

SQL Server:

```
Id | Login | Year | Month | Day | Overtime |selectboxlist| Minus |
---+-------+------+-------+-----+----------+-------------+-------+
 1 | MIPA  | 2020 |   1   |  1  |   3:00   |      2      | 1:00  |
33 | MIPA  | 2020 |   1   | 30  |   1:00   |     null    | 1:30  |
44 | MIPA  | 2020 |   2   |  1  |   4:00   |      2      | 2:00  |
77 | MIPA  | 2020 |   2   | 30  |   2:00   |     null    | 2:30  |
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Model1[nr_rows].DropdownClassList, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(enumDropDown))), "  ", new { @class = "selectboxlist" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model1[nr_rows].overtimeList , new { @class = "overtime", @type = "time"})

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model1[nr_rows].minusList, new { @class = "minus", @type = "time"})
```

Model:

```
public partial class modelCard
{
    public string overtimeList { get; set; }
    public string minusList { get; set; }
    public enumDropDown? DropdownClassList{ get; set; }
}

public enum enumDropDown
{
    test1 = 1,
    test2 = 2,
    test3 =3
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have successfully obtained the OvertimeList and its sum, you can use the same method to get the relevant data of the Minus column ，just add a where condition like below:

```
var minusListVariable= _context.Card
            .Where(x => x.Login == userName && x.Year == numberYear &&
                   x.Month < numberMonth && x.selectboxlist=="2")
            .Select(b => string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.Minus) ? TimeSpan.Zero : TimeSpan.Parse(b.Minus))
            .ToList();

var sumMinusListVariable = minusListVariable.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (t1, t2) => t1 + t2);
```